# Compare two columns in two sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have another question, even  though the last one i asked is still pending. I have a large data of over 100,000 records. I am using the code below to loop through the data so that any duplicate record will have the background colour turned to red. The code is working fine, but it is currently taking way too long to process (15-20 minutes). my question is, is there anything I can do to make the process faster?

The code:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet, wrkb As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngNew As Range
Dim intCount As Integer, intCount1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer, im As Integer

'Sheet1
Set wks = Worksheets("sheet1")
wks.Range("B2").Activate

'sheet2
Set wksb = Worksheets("sheet2")

' Return current data region.

Set rng = wks.Range("B1").CurrentRegion
Set rngNew = wksb.Range("B1").CurrentRegion

intCount = rng.Rows.Count
intCount1 = rngNew.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To intCount
            im = 2
    For im = 2 To intCount1

        If (rng.Cells(im, 2).Value = rngNew.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then

            rng.Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    Exit For
        End If

    Next im
Next
```

thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using VBA to loop through the data, you can use conditional formatting that will color the cells in a snap.

VBA is not the best solution, just because it's code. Some built-in Excel functions are much more efficient and way faster than any VBA code.

Describe the layout of the worksheet(s) and the logic that you want to apply to color-code cells.

Then a conditional formatting can be suggested. I don't have time to reverse-engineer your VBA into a workbook range.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn, I was using conditional formatting to do this in the past, but now I need to delete all duplicates from the table after report review. That is the reason for using code and I also need to do some processing on the worksheet. At the moment it has to be done within VBA until I move the data to Access later on in the future. thanks

Comment: How about the "Remove Duplicates" command on the Data ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

A helper column in one of your sheets should do it, using a `COUNTIF` formula to count the number of entries matching a condition in the other sheet. Then add a conditional format, colouring the cells red if the formula returns >0.

And what @teylyn says about VBA is quite right - it's to be avoided if you can do it with a function.

Comment: can i automate the deletion on the coloured cells after review? if yes how?

Comment: You could use a filter, then you could easily select and delete all the duplicates. Or 'Remove Duplicates' as @teylyn says.